# How can I fix my responsive css code error?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my website, when I enter with my phone, the responsive css doesn't work.
Im thinking that it's something with the css code or with the `padding`.
If I enter with my computer I can see the post correctly, but when I enter with my iPhone 7, the responsive css doesn't work.

This links are picture with the problems: 
[image1](http://elcardopoloclub.com.ar/1-2/) [image2](http://elcardopoloclub.com.ar/2-2/)

This is the code that I have done:

'

```
                            <div class="row portfolio-row ignore-thumbnail-settings" data-grid="fitRows" data-posttype-autoplay="true" data-posttype-autoplay-timeout="4000" data-posttype-autoplay-speed="700" data-posttype-autoplay-hover="true" data-posttype-loop="true" data-posttype-pagination="true" data-posttype-navigation="false" data-rtl="false">
                <div id="portfolio-post-4594" class="portfolio-column portfolio-post portfolio-hover-style-1 all casa-nueva  width1x height1x col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="">
                        <div class="portfolio-content-container">
                            <div class="portfolio-thumbnail">
                                <img width="920" height="920" src="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/920x920-850_3591.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">                                </div> 
                            <div class="portfolio-caption-content">
                                <a class="portfolio-content-link" href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/casa-nueva/" target="_self"></a>
                                <div class="portfolio-content-inner">
                                    <div class="portfolio-content-details">
                                        <h5 class="portfolio-title"><a href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/casa-nueva/" target="_self">Casa Nueva</a></h5>                                        </div>
                                                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>                        <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Hollywood Hills Contemporary

```
                            <div class="row portfolio-row ignore-thumbnail-settings" data-grid="fitRows" data-posttype-autoplay="true" data-posttype-autoplay-timeout="4000" data-posttype-autoplay-speed="700" data-posttype-autoplay-hover="true" data-posttype-loop="true" data-posttype-pagination="true" data-posttype-navigation="false" data-rtl="false">
                <div id="portfolio-post-4640" class="portfolio-column portfolio-post portfolio-hover-style-1 all oakmoreroad  width1x height1x col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="">
                        <div class="portfolio-content-container">
                            <div class="portfolio-thumbnail">
                                <img width="720" height="720" src="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/720x720-SERVICES-bedroom3-9545OakmoreRoad.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">                                </div> 
                            <div class="portfolio-caption-content">
                                <a class="portfolio-content-link" href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/oakmoreroad/" target="_self"></a>
                                <div class="portfolio-content-inner">
                                    <div class="portfolio-content-details">
                                        <h5 class="portfolio-title"><a href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/oakmoreroad/" target="_self">oakmoreroad</a></h5>                                        </div>
                                                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>                        <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Oakmore Bvld.

```
                            <div class="row portfolio-row ignore-thumbnail-settings" data-grid="fitRows" data-posttype-autoplay="true" data-posttype-autoplay-timeout="4000" data-posttype-autoplay-speed="700" data-posttype-autoplay-hover="true" data-posttype-loop="true" data-posttype-pagination="true" data-posttype-navigation="false" data-rtl="false">
                <div id="portfolio-post-4688" class="portfolio-column portfolio-post portfolio-hover-style-1 all philo  width1x height1x col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="">
                        <div class="portfolio-content-container">
                            <div class="portfolio-thumbnail">
                                <img width="920" height="920" src="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/920x920-livingroom2-080A3756.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">                                </div> 
                            <div class="portfolio-caption-content">
                                <a class="portfolio-content-link" href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/philo/" target="_self"></a>
                                <div class="portfolio-content-inner">
                                    <div class="portfolio-content-details">
                                        <h5 class="portfolio-title"><a href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/philo/" target="_self">philo</a></h5>                                        </div>
                                                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>                        <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Philo Hills Blvd.

```
                            <div class="row portfolio-row ignore-thumbnail-settings" data-grid="fitRows" data-posttype-autoplay="true" data-posttype-autoplay-timeout="4000" data-posttype-autoplay-speed="700" data-posttype-autoplay-hover="true" data-posttype-loop="true" data-posttype-pagination="true" data-posttype-navigation="false" data-rtl="false">
                <div id="portfolio-post-4718" class="portfolio-column portfolio-post portfolio-hover-style-1 all wilshire  width1x height1x col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="">
                        <div class="portfolio-content-container">
                            <div class="portfolio-thumbnail">
                                <img width="920" height="920" src="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/920x920-10450-Wilshire-Blvd-UNIT-2A-print-024-024-Bedroom-2-4200x2800-300dpi.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">                                </div> 
                            <div class="portfolio-caption-content">
                                <a class="portfolio-content-link" href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/wilshire/" target="_self"></a>
                                <div class="portfolio-content-inner">
                                    <div class="portfolio-content-details">
                                        <h5 class="portfolio-title"><a href="https://www.pampacasastaging.com/portfolio/wilshire/" target="_self">wilshire</a></h5>                                        </div>
                                                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>                        <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Wilshire Blvd.'

Comment: do you want these images to be responsive . is that you wants

Comment: I need that the blank that I have between images doesnt exist. Please see the links with images

Comment: sorry but I saw both of the images but still cannot understand what you expect. Could you please explain bit more

Comment: Please take some time to format your code properly. If you want good answers you need to make your questions clear and easy to read. Code formatting is a big part of that.

Answer (score 0):

You have got a inline content wider than screen of your phone, probably

> img width="920" height="920" .....

If you want to fix this problem making the pictures (or any element) responsive to each device, you have to express them in term of a percentage of the size of each device or using vw and vh units